# Binary with digit 2 allowed

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, functional-equations, recursion, number-systems

> How many ordered 11-tuples $(a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_{10})$ of integers
> satisfy the equation $$a_0+2a_1+2^2a_2+...+2^{10}a_{10}=2020$$ where
> $0\le a_i\le 2$ for all $0\le i\le10$ [AMC Mock](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c594864h2159345_2020_mock_amc_1012_scrabbler94)

If $f(n)$ is the number of ways that the number $n$ can be written, the [solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c594864h2159345p16509862) uses a "binary" number system where 2 is also a valid digit and shows the following recursions/functional equations:

$$1:f(2n)=f(n)+f(n-1)$$
(1 holds since you can append a zero at the end of any valid representation of $n$, or a 2 at the end of any valid representation of $n-1$ to get $2n$)

$$2: f(2n+1)=f(n)$$

(2 holds since you can append a 1 at the end of any valid representation of $n$ to get $2n+1$)
$$3: f(2^k-2)=k$$
$$4: f(4n)=f(n)+2f(n-1)$$

Are there other interesting properties of this kind of system apart from the ones above?

Both references to theory and questions will help.

Comment: It is "different" only in appearance from the usual binary form with "10" instead of "2".

Comment: It is not different only in appearance. 4 can be written 100 or 12 or 20.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I made a mistake, my brute force implementation seems to indicate the answer to your first question above is $51$.

---

Here's a list of solutions where $x=2$ that perhaps provides a bit more insight.

---

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \# & \text{Solution} \\
 1 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 2 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 3 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 4 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 5 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 6 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 7 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 8 & 2 x^9+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 9 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 10 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 11 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 12 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 13 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 14 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 15 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 16 & x^{10}+2 x^8+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 17 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 18 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 19 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 20 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 21 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 22 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 23 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 24 & x^{10}+x^9+2 x^7+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 25 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 26 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 27 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 28 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 29 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 30 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 31 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 32 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+2 x^6+2 x^5+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 33 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 34 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 35 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 36 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 37 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 38 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 39 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 40 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+2 x^5+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 41 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+x+2=2020 \\
 42 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+x^3+2 x^2+2 x=2020 \\
 43 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+2 x^3+x+2=2020 \\
 44 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+2 x^3+2 x=2020 \\
 45 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^4+2 x^3+x^2=2020 \\
 46 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+2 x^4+x+2=2020 \\
 47 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+2 x^4+2 x=2020 \\
 48 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+2 x^4+x^2=2020 \\
 49 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x+2=2020 \\
 50 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+2 x=2020 \\
 51 & x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^2=2020 \\
\end{array}$$

---

Here's the Mathematica code I used to generate the results above

```
Module[{a=Table[0,{i,1,11}],m=0,n,aSum,sumCnt=0,solList={{"#","Solution"}}},
 While[m<=3^11-1,
  n=0;
  aSum=0;
  While[n<=10,
   aSum+=a[[n+1]] 2^n;
   n++];
  If[aSum==2020,sumCnt++;
   solList=AppendTo[solList,{sumCnt,Sum[a[[n+1]]x^n,{n,0,10}]==2020}]];
  a=incA[a];
  m++];
 {m,a,aSum,sumCnt,Grid@solList,Block[{x=2},Grid@solList]}]
```

where the function incA referenced above is defined as follows:

```
incA[a_]:=Module[{b=a,n=0,done=False},
  While[n<=10&&!done,
   If[b[[n+1]]==2,b[[n+1]]=0,b[[n+1]]=b[[n+1]]+1;
    done=True];
   n++];
  b]
```

Comment: Your brute force approach verifies the mathematical solution linked to. I am interested in more mathematical properties.

Comment: @Starlight It seems to me the list of solutions illustrates a pattern, but I haven't studied it yet. Perhaps the pattern is related to some of the comments in your question above.

Comment: Also, note that the solution I linked to has the mathematical calculation for 51. Could you share the code that you used?